# Restricting Zoom in Nokia Maps ( Javascript Api)

Tags: javascript, api, here-api

I have implemented Nokia Maps using the java script Api. There are various zoom levels in the map.

Is there a way I can restrict the view of the map to a specific country ?
I mean Suppose I initialize the map with zoom level such that I can see only USA in the map. But the user can zoom out and view different countries. I don't want to completely turn off the zoom functionality because I want the user to be able to zoom in and zoom out within USA.

My map implementation is below -

```
       var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(document.getElementById("map"),
       {           
         'components': [ new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(),
                         new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
                         new nokia.maps.map.component.DistanceMeasurement(),
                         new nokia.maps.map.component.Overview(),
                         new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar(),
                         new nokia.maps.positioning.component.Positioning(),
                         new nokia.maps.map.component.ContextMenu(),
                         new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomRectangle()],
            'zoomLevel':4   ,       
            'center':[39.8282, -98.5795]            
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

To restrict the area, you will need to write an Event Listener, and listen to the `"mapviewchangeend"` event of the map. The listener can then alter the map `center` property should it fall outside of a given bounding box. To restrict the zoom add an observer to the `zoomLevel` property and limit the maximum or minimum level.

Ideally, since such functionality is re-usable it should be created as a `MapComponent` and attached to the map.

An example map restriction component (which restricts area and zoom) can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/heremaps/examples/blob/master/maps_api_for_javascript/demos/restrict-map-component/libs/restrict-map-control.js)

It can be initialised and used as follows:

```
var bounds = new nokia.maps.geo.BoundingBox(
    new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(54.8073, 5.9845),
    new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(47.4136,14.3671)
);
restrictControl = new RestrictMap(5, 20, bounds);

map.components.add(restrictControl);
```

You would just need to alter the bounds to cover the geocoordinates of the USA.